# awk, header: igore when reading, include when writing

Tags: csv, awk

i know how to ignore the column header when reading a file. i can do something like this:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 { #process here }' table > out_table
```

But if i do this, everything else other than the COLUMN HEADER is written into the output file. But i want the output file to have COLUMN HEADER also.

Of course i can do something like this, after i execute the first statement:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Column Headers\t"} {print}' Out_table > out_table_with_header
```

But this becomes a 2 step process. So is there a way to do this in a SINGE STEP itself?

In short, is there a way for me to ignore Column Header while reading file, perform operation on the data, then include Column Header when writing it to output file, in a single step (or a block of steps that takes very less response time?)

Comment: your `BEGIN{} {}` is made for and take nearly no time, and due to your conditionnal output, there is a conditional bloc (of code). Now you can have a simple bloc `{#some process;print $1 $2}` to print and header and content but it depend of you manipulation that can change the header content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your correctly, you can simply:

```
awk 'NR==1{print}; NR>1 { # process }' file
```

which can be simplified to:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR>1 { # process }' file
```

That works for a single input file.

---

If you want to process more than one file, all having the same column headers at line 1 use this:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && !h {print; h=1}; FNR>1 { # process }' file1 file2 ...
```

I'm using the variable `h` to check whether the headers have been printed already or not.

Comment: Don't test opposite conditions - `awk 'NR==1{print; next} { # process }' file`